# Is the natural gas sold to other countries by Russia produced in a more environmentally detrimental way than the natural gas sold by the US? How? Why?

Tags: usa, natural-gas, russia

In the NPR podcast and transcript [Former NSA McMaster proposes climate policy to pressure Russia](https://www.npr.org/2022/01/22/1075108292/former-nsa-mcmaster-proposes-climate-policy-to-pressure-russia) is the following exchange between reporter Michel Martin and former National Security Advisor, [General H.R. McMaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._R._McMaster):

> MARTIN: So first of all, we should say that Russia makes a lot of money from exporting natural gas through a number of pipelines to Europe, and European governments are eager to not have that supply disrupted or shut off, especially in the middle of winter. So that being said, can you describe this idea of using climate and trade policy to put pressure on Russia? What exactly are you proposing?
>
> MCMASTER: It's really important to recognize that economic security is national security, and energy security is national security. And we can't really compartmentalize these aspects of policy. They ought to be consistent with one another. **We ought to reward economically those who produce energy sources in a way that reduces carbon emissions, and this is, in particular, natural gas production and shipment. Russia - the way that Russia produces natural gas is dirty itself. The United States, the way we produce and export natural gas with LNG and others is relatively clean,** and this is a way to align economic incentives with using, in this case, natural gas as a bridge to renewables and zero-emissions energy sources. We know we can't do it really any other way, Michel. I mean, this is why, you know, Europe can't keep the lights on. And the fact that they are dependent on Russian gas has given Vladimir Putin tremendous coercive power over Europe's economies.

**Question:** Is the natural gas sold to other countries by Russia produced in a more environmentally detrimental way than the natural gas sold by the US? If so, how? Why?

Comment: I don't have quite enough reputation to add a `russia` tag

Comment: Interesting. I'll dig into this if I get the chance, but I'm going to guess that if it's true, the "how" is that Russia doesn't control for leaks as well, and the "why" is because doing so would be costly.

Comment: @LShaver Thanks! I see; the methane leaks rather than (or in combination with) CO2 produced as a bi-product somehow. Yes that makes more sense and it never occurred to me.

Comment: methane leaks are huge issue for the fossil industry in general. Much of the equipment was designed back when methane was only a problem if it exploded. It's also difficult to control leaks of a low-value product without becoming unprofitable.

Comment: @Móż ...was only *known to be* a problem...

Comment: Not directly commenting on Russian natural gas [issues](https://www.lehman.edu/faculty/rwhittaker/Day02-Research/Russia_%20Environmental%20Issues.pdf), but if the issues concerning its oil industry can be a guide the situation is bad: "The oil and gas extraction industries not only contribute to the air pollution problem in Russia, but are also significant sources of pollution in their own right. Environmental standards are weak, enforcement is poor, and small-scale accidents, pipeline leakage, and tanker spills have contaminated many areas of Russia. Oil pipelines ...

Comment: ...  leak significant volumes of oil. Serious health problems from oil pollution have been reported in the more contaminated area. Since the collapse of the Soviet Union, thieves have tapped into the pipelines and have stolen large quantities of oil from reserves at refineries in Grozny. Also, according to Russian military ecologists, an estimated 15,000 "mini-refineries" have been built. These mini-refineries, ... typically dump their residual refining wastes with little regard for the environmental consequences, contaminating the ground and water supplies, rivers and fish.

Comment: There's some country-level data from IEA [here](https://www.iea.org/reports/methane-tracker-2021), which does indeed show that Russia's emissions are both higher and more intense than those of the U.S.

Comment: Just in today, [Mapping Methane Emissions from Fossil Fuel Exploitation](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/images/149374/mapping-methane-emissions-from-fossil-fuel-exploitation). Russia has some very emission rate data.

Comment: Side note: you could rank between sources of fossil fuels, and between fossil fuels themselves, but at the end of the day/year/century we will run out of them, and along the way even a comparatively lower amount of environmental pollution still adds up. We should stop using these for low quality uses like space heating, and preferably completely.

Comment: @Fred also [Climate change: Satellites map huge methane plumes from oil and gas](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-60203683)

Comment: Probably not robust proof, but very suggestive of an answer, from the BBC article, *"By plugging these leaks, countries could save billions - including $6bn for Turkmenistan, $4bn for Russia and $1.6bn for the US, the research suggests.* If Russia could save $4bn & the US $1.6bn then Russian gas would be more detrimental to the environment than US gas.

Comment: More anecdotal data, [*Searching for methane leaks, scientists find “ultra emitters”*](https://arstechnica.com/science/2022/03/fixing-ultra-emitting-methane-leaks-is-a-low-cost-climate-win/). *In total, these leaks released 8 million metric tons of methane per year. Of this, Turkmenistan and Russia were responsible for close to 1 million metric tons per year each, while the US ranked third, with a little under 0.5 million metric tons per year.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, yes; but difficult to quantify. Environment and safety have lower priorities in Russia ( and other countries) than in the west.As an example I remember touring a Russian steel mill with no safety glasses, no hardhat, etc, unless you brought your own. I felt undressed compared to being in a western mill. Starting with the well drilling mud which is contained and treated in the west, it is pretty much left in the mud pits unless some is salvaged for the next well in Russia. Admitted all I have is anecdotal; like Amoco drillers refused to go back to Russian drill site after first trip due to safety concerns (about 1990). However , Russians want to make money selling oil and gas, so they lose as little as possible.