# How much methane is lost in extraction and transmision from different sources?

Tags: energy, natural-gas, climate-change

In recent years there has been a significant move towards electricity generation from natural gas.  This has in large part been driven by the desire to reduce green house gas release.  However methane is a potent green house gas, with a [global warming potential of 28 - 36 times](https://www.epa.gov/ghgemissions/understanding-global-warming-potentials) that of CO2, making leaks a significant problem.

Recently there has developed tension between western Europe and Russia.  One potential result could be Europe getting more of its gas as liquid natural gas from the United States, shipped by boat, and less from the Russian Federation, shipped by pipeline.

Do we have any data on the extraction and transmission losses of natural gas?  In particular, do we know if it is better to get it from the US or Russia?  Intuitively, one may suppose that the opportunities for leaks would be greater with shipping by sea, but it is also possible that differences in regulations around extraction would have a bigger difference.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Your question looks similar to [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/12044/)?

Comment: I do not know how I missed that, it answers my question.  Should I delete my question do you think?

Comment: No worries. If you have no additional questions then please delete. Alternatively we can close it as a duplicate.